# Если создавать высоконагруженное Web-приложение какой инструмент предпочтительнее ?

Tags: python, ruby

Если создавать высоконагруженное Web-приложение какой инструмент предпочтительнее Ruby on Rails или Python(Pyramid,Django) ? Имеется ввиду скорость работы, стабильность, многофункциональность, тоесть максимально укомплектованный надёжный инструмент ! Благодарю **...**

Comment: Пишут что быстрее ruby, но мне, ни тот ни тот язык программирования не нравится, это только по статьям

Comment: Но ruby все равно лучше будет, думаю.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 спасибо за ответ ! Скажите, а какие причины того что вам не нравятся оба этих языка ? Просто хочу знать ваше мнение !

Comment: В той фирме где я работал раньше было много python кода, в котором просто нереально было разобраться, или его так писали, или сам язык мне не нравится, я не думаю что это у меня проблемы, так как я отучился на программиста и давно очень программирую, спокойно читаю программы на С++ или PHP если брать веб. Ruby начинал учить вроде нормально, но сильно большие проекты не разбирал, может быть будет то же что и с питоном. Стандартный РHP по-моему лучше, несмотря на говнокод. Смотря как писать на PHP, или другом языке.  Если не хочется PHP тогда Ruby. А возможности одинаковые думаю.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо !

Comment: @MAX_Vovk, Не за что, это мое личное предпочтение, просто.

Comment: Вопрос странный.

Пишите на том, что хорошо знаете. Если ничего хорошо не знаете, то высоконагруженное приложение написать вряд ли сможете.

Answer (score -1):

Преимущество веб-фреймворков Ruby (Rails, Padrino, Sinatra, etc) в скорости написания кода. Работают они стабильно но медленно и требуют до фига памяти. Использовать их имеет смысл только для больших проектов, где траты на мощный сервер будут оправданы. Питон категорически нестабилен, сам по себе, и страдает утечками памяти. Можно использовать PHP+ADODB или, для более сложных задач, Qt.

Comment: Потребление памяти очень сильно зависит от количества используемых библиотек. На "пустом" проекте Sinatra ест 10МБ памяти, а с простым, но достаточным боевым набором (postgres, bcrypt, шаблонизатор) - около 40МБ на ядро. Это много? У меня skype 600МБ ест и Chrome больше гига.


Ruby тоже страдает утечками, и это привело к чудо-костылю в виде суффикса f к литералам в 2.1 и необходимости избегать преобразования к символам всего, что идёт на входе из внешних источников.


Никто не без изьяна, надо просто уметь пользоваться.

Comment: Просто я не видел ни единого приложения на Питоне, которое бы утечками НЕ страдало. Уже давно вычистил и заменил на сишные аналоги всё написанное на на нём, что мог, на своём компе. На Руби же пряморукие программисты действительно пишут годные вещи.

Answer (score -2):

если выбор стоит только между питоном и руби, то я бы попробовал твистед, торнадо

Comment: Просто на ASP.NET писать слишком дорого и как по мне сложнее ...

Comment: так есть же еще компилируемые языки

Comment: А почему? Вы представьте себе такой же ответ, который советует Rails. И как задавшему вопрос решить между двумя вашими радикально противоположенными ответами?

Comment: ну рэйлс в нагруженном проекте разже что фронтенд может подавать. писать на нём бэкенд в высоконагруженном(!) проекте это ССЗБ.

Comment: @actionless: Уверен, то же самое можно сказать и про python/twisted.

Автор вопроса, кстати, не уточнял, может быть это высоконагруженная раздача страницы "Hello, %username%". В таком случае практически все равны. И ваш ответ, опять же, совершенно не очевиден.

Comment: почему вы в это уверены? :)

Answer (score -2):

руби по производительности самый медленный

если допустим время большого цикла замерить, так проиграет раз в 5 аналогичному циклу на питоне

самый быстрый php

остальное высоконагруженной как вы говорите достигается не языком а распределением по серверам

Comment: ruby по большинству тестов [быстрее](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=yarv&lang2=python3&data=u64) python'а, ещё и частенько есть меньше памяти.

А что до скриптовых языков (Ruby, Python, Perl, Lua, JS), так и вообще JS впереди всех с большим отрывом. Что в общем совсем не повод прыгать в объятья Node.js.

Comment: где это вы прочитали?:)

Comment: ссылку-то щёлкали?

Comment: ответу автору, руби быстрее питона да, когда то сам тестил